# Spring/Grails: Is there a limitation on the amount of data that can be stored on the session variable?

Tags: grails, httpsession

How much data can be stored on session? Is there a performance disadvantage of storing too much data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No limit is imposed by grails / spring, neither any limit is imposed by servers. So there's no limit other then the memory / java heap limit.

Obviously storing data in session takes memory, and hence storing too much data in memory can have performance impacts especially if you have large number of simultaneous users.